# Unable to detach AWS IAM role from my instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I tried to detach one of my IAM role from my instance (still running) and got a response of successful detachment.

Afterwards I tried to attach a new IAM role to the exactly same instance, however, this message occured: **The association <*AssociationId*> is not the active association.**

After using `aws ec2 describe-iam-instance-profile-associations` to check the IAM instance profile associations, I found that the state is **disassociating**. And I rechecked the associations the other day, it's still stuck at **disassociating**.

Then I tried `aws ec2 associate-iam-instance-profile` to associate my instance with a new role, but all I got is another instance association stuck at **associating**.

I also tried `replace-iam-instance-profile-association` and the same showed up: **The association <*AssociationId*> is not the active association.**

And rebooting instance did not work either.

Any solutions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed this issue by launching a new instance base on the EBS snapshot of the problematic instance, which is the last thing I wanna do.

Anyway, this could be considered as a workaround. :(

It really sucks that you have to pay to create AWS technical support cases.

Answer (score 1):

Found an easy solution for this!
Hope this helps some people finding this.
After getting stuck in the "disassociating" or "associating" state, use the aws CLI to find the associations that causes the problem (They will be stuck at the state ""disassociating" or "associating""):

```
aws ec2 describe-iam-instance-profile-associations
```

After finding them use:

```
aws ec2 disassociate-iam-instance-profile --association-id iip-assoc-xxxxxx
```

to remove them. Not quite intuitive but you can actually remove the ones in the state "disassociating" after that you can add a new role/instance-profile.

Comment: in my case this just confirms that the profile is stuck in the disassociating state. There is no change running the disassociate-iam-instance-profile command.

Comment: @badfun interesting, can you post the commands you tried, their output and the result you hoped for?

Answer (score 0):

**Error** : *Unable to detach, there are no existing instance profile associations.
While you are trying to add Role to EC2 instance*

**Debug and Verify:**

run > `aws iam list-instance-profiles`

command output :

```
{
    "InstanceProfiles": []
}
```

run > `aws iam list-instance-profiles-for-role --role-name Your-Role-Name`

command output :

```
{
    "InstanceProfiles": []
}
```

**Solution :**

run > `aws iam create-instance-profile --instance-profile-name profile-name-sameas-role-name`

run > `aws iam add-role-to-instance-profile --instance-profile-name profile-name-sameas-role-name --role-name role-name`

**Done !!**

*Go Back to EC2 dashboard and try to Add the IAM Role again. This time it should work.*